# Constructor containing class dependencies

Tags: dependencies, constructors

Is it a best practice to initialize class dependencies in a constructor or should a class be initialized in the method where it is used. Let's say we have the following situation, and PriceCalcService is used only in a couple of methods. Order also takes other parameters, and sets its state.

```
public class ShippingService() { .......... }

public class Order() {
    public string SomeOrderProperty;
    private PriceCalcService priceCalcService;

    public Order(string someOrderproperty) {
         priceCalcService= new PriceCalcService();
         SomeOrderProperty = someOrderProperty;
    }

    public void Method1() {
         PriceCalcService.MethodX();
    }
    .......
}
```

Or should the PriceCalcService be initialized only in the methods that use it?

```
public class PriceCalcService() { .......... }  

public class Order() {

    public string SomeOrderProperty;
    public Order(string someOrderproperty) {
         SomeOrderProperty = someOrderproperty;
    }

    public void Method1() {
         new PriceCalcService().MethodX();
    }
    .......
}
```

First example: Advantage: We can see the dependencies
               Disadvantage: We instantiate a class even if it is not used. Which method should I choose?

Comment: In you example, the `Order` class doesn't have a dependency to the `PriceCalcService`. Therefore you can just drop the method `Method1` and use the `PriceCalcService` somewhere else.

Answer (score 8):

> Is it a best practice to initialize class dependencies in a constructor or should a class be initialized in the method where it is used

No. Neither is good practice. Good practice is to:

1. reference those dependencies via interfaces,
2. Inject the dependencies via the constructor

So the code might look something like:

```
public class Order() {
    private IShippingService shippingService;

    public Order(IShippingService shippingService) {
         this.shippingService = shippingService;
    }

    public void Method1() {
        shippingService.MethodX();
    }
    .......
}
```

Comment: some say that the 'I' prefix for interfaces are a bad pratice.

Comment: @linuxunil, That is entirely dependent on the language, eg using `I` to prefix interfaces in Java is going against that language's conventions. Not using them in C# would be failing to follow that language's conventions. They are used here to emphasise it's an interface as the question is language-agnostic.

Comment: that's way i said 'some say'... in java abstract classes usually have an 'Abstract' prefix - apache does this a lot - so i don't know why not let intefaces have the 'I' prefix. But let's not start this discussion here as it has nothing to do with the OP question ;)

Comment: Thanks for the answer David Arno. I don't want to use Dependency Injection, because I want to do OOP style programming and if I use DI I will kinda end up with a procedural programming style. I want to pass additional parameters beside class dependencies to set up state for the object. Sorry I forgot to mention that I will update my question.

Comment: @Icebraker, "*I want to do OOP style programming and if I use DI I will kinda end up with a procedural programming style*". This statement is non-sequitur. Object constructor-based DI is, by definition, an OOP-only solution.

Comment: @David Arno, sorry. I meant that I want to set state as well in the object, throught the constructor.

Comment: @Icebraker The Shipping service must take instances of orders in the service methods not the inverse. The responsibility of an Order Object is to hold information of an order. The shipping service is responsible of containing methods that take an order to do the shipping.

Comment: Your right, Wrote the example in a  hurry. But the question is still the same. Which one is the best practice.

Comment: @Icebraker, "*But the question is still the same. Which one is the best practice*". Neither; both are bad practice as you are creating tight coupling between your class and its dependencies. Which of two bad practices is better is a moot point.

Comment: @David Arno, In my opinion using a lot of DI is the first step to anemic domain model. My question was if you follow a DDD and do OOP which of those 2 would be the best choice, or if you have a better solution. Are you still sure that DI is the way to go with DDD?

Comment: @Icebraker, all is becoming clear now. Take a read of [The Rotten Domain Model is dead; long live the Abstracted Domain Model](http://www.davidarno.org/2016/02/24/the-rotten-domain-model-is-dead-long-live-the-abstracted-domain-model/) for my thoughts on the nonsense of the "rich vs anaemic domain models". Wake up, the OO world has changed in the last 15 years...

Answer (score 3):

## Let the [POJO](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plain_Old_Java_Object) be the [POJO](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plain_Old_Java_Object).

The responsibility of an Order Object is to hold information of an order.

```
public class Order() {

    //let the properties of the pojo be private
    private String orderDescription;

    public Order(String orderDescription) {
       this.orderDescription = orderDescription;
    }

    //getters/setters
}
```

## Let the Service be the service.

The service is responsible of containing methods that take an order and operate on them.

```
public class ShippingService() { 
  public void processShipping(Order order){
    //write the body of the method that takes the order and do the shipping.
  }
}
```

In a abstract way, you have an Object that is a POJO. Then you have a service that holds the ways of work with that Object. That way you can develop your object - adding new properties - and the service - adding new functionality - in a separate way.

Comment: You are right, but that way you will end up in a procedural style of programming. I wanted to have data + operations at the same place, thus doing oop style programming.

Comment: are refering to [DDD] ? : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain-driven_design

Comment: yepp, something like that.

Answer (score 1):

In general, if we are talking about a business application and you wish to support automated unit testing, follow these rules:

1. Dependencies should be injected.
2. Other initialization should be done outside the constructor, just before it is actually needed (["lazy"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lazy_initialization))

This allows a unit testing framework to isolate method logic from constructor logic, while supplying mock interfaces via DI.

On the other hand, if we are talking about a realtime application such as a video game, you should probably do all of the initialization in the constructor so that the performance of the code is predictable.